# Can't get decimals to display in text field for Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, textbox, currency, bigdecimal, number-to-currency

I have a brief question... pretty new to rails, and I was wondering if you could help me with an issue that I'm having in code. I have a set of input boxes (it's an online app that asks for revenues and expenses) where I would like to format the currency. I've been using the following line of code for other independent input boxes (text_fields) within the app, but for some reason, it wont work when i try to add it to the income statement fields

code I have been using:

```
= f.text_field :user_nummber, :value=>number_to_currency(f.object.user_number)
```

the area of code i've been having issues with:

```
 = f.fields_for :income_statements do |ff|
        .section_total.income_statement{ :id => "income_statement_#{ff.object.year}" }
          = ff.hidden_field :id
          = ff.hidden_field :year
          %h3.financials_year= ff.object.year

          .financials_data
            .section
              %h2.green_text Revenue
              %div{:class => "label_rightalign_investor field"}
                = ff.label :net_sales
                = ff.text_field :net_sales, :value=>number_to_currency(ff.object.net_sales), :class => 'add'
              %div{:class => "label_rightalign_investor field"}
                = ff.label :interest_income
                = ff.text_field :interest_income, :value=>number_to_currency(ff.object.interest_income), :class => 'add'
              %div{:class => "label_rightalign_investor field", :style => 'font-weight: bold' }
                = label_tag 'Total'
                = text_field_tag 'total_revenue', '', :class => 'calculate add_total', :readonly => true
```

Please note that the final total_revenue field calculates the values with class:add (net sales & interest income)

Any help in what i'm doing wrong, and why my text_fields (input box) does not display values in the following format: $x,xxx.00 would be appreciated.

I sincerely thank you for your help and time!

Comment: What IS being displayed instead?

Comment: Nothing... just the standard numbers... if i type 200000 i would like for it to display $200,000.00 or at least $200,000, instead it simply displays 200000

Comment: Is it just the last text field (total_revenue) that displays this behavior, or all text fields in the fields_for section?

Comment: @Thilo, all the text fields in the fields_for section. I'm aware that I did not include the :value property to the last field--I should have mentioned that, sorry.

Comment: I know this is very old and you probably solved it, but could it be something as silly as a typo? In the first text_field you have `user_nummber` instead of `user_number`

Answer (score 0):

Try add the precision parameter like this:

```
<%= f.text_field :user_number, :value => number_to_currency(f.object.user_number, :precision => 3) %>
```

Check here for more details:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency

Hope it helps you somehow!

Comment: @ Kleber: Thanks for the link mate; however, my issue actually is that it's not displaying anything at all... not just the location or accuracy of the decimal point.